# Databinding with two nested ng-repeat does not work

Tags: angularjs, data-binding

Unfortuantely two data binding does not work when having two nested ng-repeat with textboxes. The first hierarchy with prop works but the second level down in sensor does not bind the values back into the model.

The affected page can be called under http://wotcloudclient.azurewebsites.net/#/Thing/Create
User: wagner
Password: test

Thanks in advance

```
<div class="well" ng-repeat="prop in properties">
                    <div class="form-group form-inline">
                        <h4 ng-show="prop.isMainThing">General</h4>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="prop.name" placeholder="Name" ng-show="!prop.isMainThing" required>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="prop.description" placeholder="Description" ng-show="!prop.isMainThing">
                        <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" ng-click="removeThing(prop)" ng-show="!prop.isMainThing"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span> </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group form-inline" ng-repeat="sensor in prop.sensors" style="margin-left: 20px">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" ng-model="sensor.name" placeholder="Sensor name" required>
                        <select class="form-control input-sm" ng-model="sensor.datatype" ng-options="item.id as item.name for item in datatypes">
                        </select>
                        <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" ng-click="removeSensor(prop, sensor)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span> </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" ng-click="addNewSensor(prop)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> <span>Add Sensor</span></button>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

[image]

Comment: Can you provide plunker? any errors you see? what is the structure of the prop object?

Comment: I have provided the site url and the credentials above. the structure looks like this: [{"id":0,"name":"General","description":"test","isMainThing":true,"sensors":[[{"name":"","datatype":""}],[{"name":"","datatype":""}]],"$$hashKey":"object:6"}] Where the second level binding with name and datatype of the sensors does not work

Comment: Have you noticed that each sensor in sensors is an array with one object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you sensors array is an array of arrays, each sensor is an array with one object. If you change sensors to be an array of objects or change the code to:

sensor.property -> sensor[0].property

```
<input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" ng-model="sensor[0].name" placeholder="Sensor name" required>
```

It should work, as written in the comment if you prove a plunker it will be easier to help you.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. It worked. But unfortunately i want to use the same view for add and edit the graph. When i render the graph in the UI with sensor[0] it does not show the correct text. It's empty?